# Return all above zero values in a row for each Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Gurus,
I need your support to skip all Less than or Equal to 0 values for each customer in following data. Specifically script should skip all columns which contain less than or equal to 0 values.

Input Data and Required Output is available in screenshot for reference

so the idea is, values in all columns from column C to H should remain as is until the SUM of these columns exceed the value mentioned in B column (TOTAL DEPOSIT) and then remaining should be adjust for last value (see attached screenshot for reference)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #input
CREATE TABLE #input
(
    [CONTACT NO] VARCHAR(15),
    [TOTAL DEPOSIT] BIGINT,
    IBFT BIGINT,
    P2P BIGINT, 
    UBP BIGINT,
    MAOTC BIGINT,
    WITHDRAWAL BIGINT,
    AIRTIME BIGINT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92342xxxxx63',1540,0,1540,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92343xxxxx47',42334,55000,17710,0,0,0,1045)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92343xxxxx05',5750,53450,5000,0,0,0,2050)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92347xxxxx53',2000,0,2800,0,0,2000,570)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92348xxxxx62',8250,0,0,0,8000,14900,45)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92348xxxxx66',40,0,0,0,0,0,40)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92303xxxxx76',400,0,1507,0,0,0,300)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92300xxxxx90',200,0,0,0,0,0,80)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92321xxxxx93',14040,11940,101180,30198,0,0,3268)
INSERT INTO #input VALUES('92333xxxxx91',45000,50000,0,0,0,0,0)
GO


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #output1
SELECT l2.*
        , CASE
            WHEN (l2.REMAINING3 - l2.MAOTC2) < 0 THEN 0
            ELSE (l2.REMAINING3 - l2.MAOTC2)
        END AS [REMAINING4]
INTO #output1
FROM (
    SELECT l.*
            , CASE
                WHEN l.MAOTC = 0 THEN 0
                WHEN l.MAOTC > l.[REMAINING3] THEN l.[REMAINING3]
                WHEN l.MAOTC <= l.[REMAINING3] THEN l.MAOTC
                ELSE l.[REMAINING3]
            END AS [MAOTC2]
    FROM (
        SELECT k2.*
                , CASE
                    WHEN (k2.REMAINING2 - k2.UBP2) < 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE (k2.REMAINING2 - k2.UBP2)
                END AS [REMAINING3]
        FROM (
            SELECT k.*
                    , CASE
                        WHEN k.UBP = 0 THEN 0
                        WHEN k.UBP > k.[REMAINING2] THEN k.[REMAINING2]
                        WHEN k.UBP <= k.[REMAINING2] THEN k.UBP
                        ELSE k.[REMAINING2]
                    END AS [UBP2]
            FROM (
                SELECT j2.*
                        , CASE
                            WHEN (j2.[REMAINING1] - j2.P2P2) < 0 THEN 0
                            ELSE (j2.[REMAINING1] - j2.P2P2)
                        END AS [REMAINING2]
                FROM (
                    SELECT j.*
                            , CASE
                                WHEN j.P2P = 0 THEN 0
                                WHEN j.P2P > j.[REMAINING1] THEN j.[REMAINING1]
                                WHEN j.P2P <= j.[REMAINING1] THEN j.P2P
                                ELSE j.[REMAINING1]
                            END AS [P2P2]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT i2.*
                                , CASE
                                    WHEN (i2.[TOTAL DEPOSIT] - i2.IBFT2) < 0 THEN 0
                                    ELSE (i2.[TOTAL DEPOSIT] - i2.IBFT2)
                                END AS [REMAINING1]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT *
                                    , CASE
                                        WHEN i.IBFT = 0 THEN 0
                                        WHEN i.IBFT > i.[TOTAL DEPOSIT] THEN i.[TOTAL DEPOSIT]
                                        WHEN i.IBFT <= i.[TOTAL DEPOSIT] THEN i.IBFT
                                        ELSE i.[TOTAL DEPOSIT]
                                    END AS [IBFT2]
                            FROM #input i
                        ) i2
                    ) j
                ) j2
            ) k
        ) k2
    ) l
) l2
GO


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #output2
SELECT n2.*
     , CASE
           WHEN (n2.REMAINING5 - n2.AIRTIME2) < 0 THEN 0
           ELSE (n2.REMAINING5 - n2.AIRTIME2)
       END AS [REMAINING DEPOSIT]
INTO #output2
FROM (
    SELECT n.*
         , CASE
               WHEN n.AIRTIME = 0 THEN 0
               WHEN n.AIRTIME > n.[REMAINING5] THEN n.[REMAINING5]
               WHEN n.AIRTIME <= n.[REMAINING5] THEN n.AIRTIME
               ELSE n.[REMAINING5]
           END AS [AIRTIME2]
    FROM (
        SELECT m2.*
             , CASE
                   WHEN (m2.REMAINING4 - m2.WITHDRAWAL2) < 0 THEN 0
                   ELSE (m2.REMAINING4 - m2.WITHDRAWAL2)
               END AS [REMAINING5]
        FROM (
            SELECT m.*
                 , CASE
                       WHEN m.WITHDRAWAL = 0 THEN 0
                       WHEN m.WITHDRAWAL > m.[REMAINING4] THEN m.[REMAINING4]
                       WHEN m.WITHDRAWAL <= m.[REMAINING4] THEN m.WITHDRAWAL
                       ELSE m.[REMAINING4]
                   END AS [WITHDRAWAL2]
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM #output1 o
            ) m
        ) m2
    ) n
) n2
GO


SELECT *
FROM #output2 o
GO
```

[image]

Comment: What code do you have so far for your query?

Comment: I've tried case statement but it did not worked for me

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code that dd not work, and explain what didn't work

Comment: @Charlieface sorry for delay, I was working on code alongside as well. I've added the code but 
1. it is too inefficient for 5 million records
2. it is too lengthy and complex that it could not run in 1 block so I have to break it in two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer which follows you could incorporate the first and last update into the second one but I think splitting it out like this makes the code easier to read and therefore easier to maintain.

I think it is self explanatory, but if you require clarification let me know.

```
DECLARE @input TABLE
(
    CONTACT_NO      VARCHAR(15),
    TOTAL_DEPOSIT   BIGINT,
    IBFT            BIGINT,
    P2P             BIGINT, 
    UBP             BIGINT,
    MAOTC           BIGINT,
    WITHDRAWAL      BIGINT,
    AIRTIME         BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92342xxxxx63',1540,0,1540,0,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92343xxxxx47',42334,55000,17710,0,0,0,1045)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92343xxxxx05',5750,53450,5000,0,0,0,2050)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92347xxxxx53',2000,0,2800,0,0,2000,570)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92348xxxxx62',8250,0,0,0,8000,14900,45)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92348xxxxx66',40,0,0,0,0,0,40)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92303xxxxx76',400,0,1507,0,0,0,300)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92300xxxxx90',200,0,0,0,0,0,80)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92321xxxxx93',14040,11940,101180,30198,0,0,3268)
INSERT INTO @input VALUES('92333xxxxx91',45000,50000,0,0,0,0,0)

-- To eliminate the need to handle the case where the existing value is less than 0 just make it 0
UPDATE @input
   SET IBFT       = CASE WHEN IBFT       < 0 THEN 0 ELSE IBFT       END,                   
       P2P        = CASE WHEN P2P        < 0 THEN 0 ELSE P2P        END,                   
       UBP        = CASE WHEN UBP        < 0 THEN 0 ELSE UBP        END,               
       MAOTC      = CASE WHEN MAOTC      < 0 THEN 0 ELSE MAOTC      END,           
       WITHDRAWAL = CASE WHEN WITHDRAWAL < 0 THEN 0 ELSE WITHDRAWAL END,       
       AIRTIME    = CASE WHEN AIRTIME    < 0 THEN 0 ELSE AIRTIME    END   

UPDATE @input
   SET IBFT       = CASE WHEN IBFT        > TOTAL_DEPOSIT 
                            THEN TOTAL_DEPOSIT 
                         ELSE IBFT 
                     END,
       P2P        = CASE WHEN P2P        <= TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT 
                            THEN P2P 
                         ELSE TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT 
                     END,
       UBP        = CASE WHEN UBP        <= TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P 
                            THEN UBP 
                         ELSE TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P 
                     END,
       MAOTC      = CASE WHEN MAOTC      <= TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP 
                            THEN MAOTC 
                         ELSE TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP 
                     END,
       WITHDRAWAL = CASE WHEN WITHDRAWAL <= TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP - MAOTC 
                            THEN WITHDRAWAL 
                         ELSE TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP - MAOTC 
                     END,
       AIRTIME    = CASE WHEN AIRTIME    <= TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP - MAOTC - WITHDRAWAL 
                            THEN AIRTIME 
                         ELSE TOTAL_DEPOSIT - IBFT - P2P - UBP - MAOTC - WITHDRAWAL 
                     END

UPDATE @input
   SET P2P        = CASE WHEN P2P        < 0 THEN 0 ELSE P2P        END,                   
       UBP        = CASE WHEN UBP        < 0 THEN 0 ELSE UBP        END,               
       MAOTC      = CASE WHEN MAOTC      < 0 THEN 0 ELSE MAOTC      END,           
       WITHDRAWAL = CASE WHEN WITHDRAWAL < 0 THEN 0 ELSE WITHDRAWAL END,       
       AIRTIME    = CASE WHEN AIRTIME    < 0 THEN 0 ELSE AIRTIME    END
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this is understandable and pretty efficient as well.